# How can use computed for v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I got data from API using computed. "UserModule.userInfo.usrEmail" is the state in my vuex. Like below:

```
data() {
    return {
      vModel: {
        email: {
          value: "",
        },
      }
   }
}

computed: {
   email:{
      get: function(){
        return UserModule.userInfo ? UserModule.userInfo.usrEmail : "";
      },
      set : function(email){
        this.vModel.email.value = email
      }
    },
 }
```

And then show it to user like below:

```
<input v-model="email"></input>
```

User can edit email and also cancel their edit process and return to their previous data but in edit everything was correct but when i want to cancel this process my previous data did not show in the input and i saw my new data which is not correct i want to cancel it. This is my cancel method on input:

```
resetInput(input) {
      this.vModel.email.value = this.email
    },
```

"this.email" refer to my computed which is get data from API.

How can i write this cancel process correctly and see my previous data in input tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can use this solution:

```js
data() {
  return {
    useGet :{
      email: true,
    },
  }
}
```

in your method:

```js
resetInput(input) {
  this.useGet.email = true
},
```

and in your computed:

```js
email: {
  get: function () {
    if (this.useGet.email) {
      return UserModule.userInfo ? UserModule.userInfo.usrEmail : ""
    }
    return ""
  },
  set: function (email) {
    this.useGet.email = false
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because of your `UserModule.userInfo.usrEmail`.

this state does not update.
your `get` in computed will be work when your `UserModule.userInfo.usrEmail` changes.

Comment: But i dont want to change my "UserModule.userInfo.usrEmail". This is a state that i store user email in it.